# LoRa HAT communication module don't send anything

Tags: python, python-3, communication

I'm working now an long range communication system, and I need help. I can't use GSM, WIFI, etc. I test one LoRa Raspberry pi shield, and I bought this: [link](https://www.waveshare.com/sx1262-868m-lora-hat.htm), and I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SX1262_868M_LoRa_HAT). Ofc I have tested other tutorials eg.: [this](https://www.spotpear.com/index/study/detail/id/244.html), [this lib](https://github.com/ehong-tl/micropySX126X), and others. None of them worked.
I have bought another 2 modules, because maybe my firs purchased modules didn't worked, but this wasn't the problem. (I didn't read any datas from the other device in receiver module, but in the sender the TX led was activated)

I want to communicate up to 30km (with a direct view), and I want to send datas about 100kbit per second.

So if you find another way to solve this problem (e.g. better turorial), I will be greatful. I'm open to any other solutions, ideas. Thanks for your help.

*(If this isn't the best forum for this, I'm sorry)*

Comment: `I bought this: link, and I have followed this tutorial. Ofc I have tested other tutorials eg.: this, this lib, and others` what link, what tutorial, which 'other tutorials', which libs? Your query is lacking in usable information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the links, and I will try to be more specific.